# How to perform a real time search and filter on a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been Googling and searching Stack Overflow for a while, but I just can't get around this problem.

I have a standard HTML table, containing, say, fruit. Like so:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Above this I have a text box, which I would like to search the table as a user types. So, if they type `Gre` for example, the Orange row of the table would disapear, leaving the Apple and Grapes. If they carried on and typed `Green Gr` the Apple row should disapear, leaving just grapes. I hope this is clear.

And, should the user delete some or all of their query from the text box, I should like all of the rows that now match the query to reappear.

While I know how to remove a table row in jQuery, I have little idea about how to go about doing the search and removing rows selectively based on this. Is there a simple solution to this? Or a plugin?

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be brilliant.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.marceble.com/2010/02/simple-jquery-table-row-filter/

Answer (score 341, accepted):

I created these examples.

#### Simple [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) search

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/2/

#### Regular expression search

More advanced functionality using regular expressions will allow you to search words in any order in the row. It will work the same if you type `apple green` or `green apple`:

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/7BUmG/1133/

#### Debounce

When you implement table filtering with search over multiple rows and columns it is very important that you consider performance and search speed/optimisation. Simply saying you should not run search function on every single keystroke, it's not necessary. To prevent filtering to run too often you should debounce it. Above code example will become:

```
$('#search').keyup(debounce(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    // etc...
}, 300));
```

You can pick any debounce implementation, for example from Lodash [_.debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce), or you can use something very simple like I use in next demos (debounce from [here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)): http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/6230/ and http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/6231/.

Comment: I'm pretty green with this stuff, but if I want to incorporate this into my table, do I just need to change the `#table` to the `id` of my table?  Would there need to be additional changes to work with `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags?  I've included the script and html from the jsfiddle link, changing the `#id`, but I get no filtering.

Comment: @JoshP Sctipt works with all the rows. If you want to filter only those inside the `<tbody>` you should change to `var $rows = $('#id-of-your-table tbody tr');`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had a hunch that was it.  Lastly, does this require a particular library be included?

Comment: @JoshP No, nothing but jQuery is required. Just make sure you run your code in DOMReady or after HTML is loaded.

Comment: @dfsq great answer! I was going row by row and hiding each row but your code is much more straight forward and effective

Comment: what js version should i use

Comment: this works on Jquery 1.5.1+ as far as i know dont have lower versions to check with ..

Comment: I would recommend to enhance this approach because it is quite resource consuming. Put all the refined strings into an array of objects with two fields: a reference to the `<tr>` DOMElement and the string. This way, on `keyup()` you search those strings (which is way faster) and have the corresponding rows ready to be manipulated. That first costly setup procedure should then be executed just once right after loading. All  these changes are just minor fixes, the actual central part still remains as shown in this answer. This approach is also possible and pretty easy to implement w/o jQuery.

Comment: @dfsq What if we want to skip  the first row from check ?

Comment: @confusedMind Use `$('#table tr:not(:first)')` selector.

Comment: @dfsq can you please explain what the !~ does in the return statement in the filter function? Much appreciated.

Comment: @Addy75 [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9316656/949476) is a good explanation. Basically, this is shorter check for -1. It should actually be `return text.indexOf(val) == -1;` as much more readable.

Comment: This is what I call Poetry, great work and thanks, I used to use a very complicated code, but this is simple and straight forward.  **I just wold like to know if I have different tables in the same page with different `ids` and each table has its own filtering `input` field.  How can I use this single jQuery to be applied on all of them.  Or do I have to create a specific jQuery function to each table?**

Comment: @SULTAN In this case it's better to create a wrapper function in order to not duplicated code. But the best approach is to wrap the code into custom mini-plugin. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/m0k6pkbb/

Comment: Great, and works, thanks.  Is there away to **count the number of filtered rows**? I tried to use `$rows.length` but that keeps giving me the original rows before filtering!

Comment: What if I need to filter rows by just checking the values in the first column?

Comment: @FredK The simples thing you can do then is to bind click event to necessary table cells, take text content of the cell, set it as filter input value and trigger "keyup" like if it was entered by typing. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/3299/

Comment: @dfsq thanks for answer but I didn't mean "checking" for clicking! I mean: I'd like to get rows by just searching in the values of the first column and not of the other ones.

Comment: @FredK Oh, I misread as "clicking" :) What you need to do is to take text from the first column only `text = $(this.cells[0]).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/3300/

Comment: @dfsq I get these warnings from my js lint/compiler for the first script: `Unexpected use of '~'.` and `Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.` and this for the 2nd one: `Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor.`

Comment: @FredK Regarding `~` I already explained it in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table/9127872?noredirect=1#comment50492830_9127872) comment. Also use `===` if your jshint requires it. And finally `new RegExp`.

Comment: Really a great solution. My Questions: is it possible to search only in a specific column instead all columns? what change will be required? Thanks

Comment: @UmairIdrees Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table/9127872#comment51629468_9127872) comment. There it searches in the first column `this.cells[0]` where `0` is the index. Change it to necessary one.

Comment: How can i make this work if I fill the rows programatically?

Comment: @Sin5k4 How exactly do you fill rows?

Comment: with jquery:            $.each(j.list, function (i, item) {
                var r = "<tr>";
                r += "<td onclick='getselectedcustomerdocu(\"" + item.ID + "\");' class='table-sub-title'>" + item.ID + "</td>";
                r += "<td class='table-sub-title'>" + item.firmaName + "</td>";
                r += "</tr>";
                $("#tablecustrows").append(r);

Comment: @Sin5k4 In this case nothing changes, just initialise `$rows` after the table in built.

Comment: interesting i couldnt get it to work with :/ the html is as :<div id="table_cust">
    <table id="tablecust" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th class="table-title">ID</th>
            <th class="table-title">Cust</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="tablecustrows">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div> and i call the rows with :         var $rows = $('#tablecust tbody tr:not(:first)');

Comment: @Sin5k4 You can create a demo with the problem.

Comment: @dfsq: which solution would you suggest if you had to work with a table in Oracle DB (which contains adresses and has 2,6 Mio rows and 10 columns) and you want to search the table as the user types (the frontend is made with PHP)? The reason I am doing this is to prevent the users to enter wrong addresses manually which causes the poor data quality. A solution that allows the users to SELECT values from the Addresses table would resolve the data quality problem.

Comment: @dfsq What if I have two input text fields and each of them searches rows by different columns. How can I combine them? So, for example, result of search by the first input text field may be used as a data for the second one.

Comment: Just to mention if you use this answer wrap the $(document).onReady around it when you add it to your code--I had to do this for django.

Comment: How would you do this for a nested table? Search does not filter the nested table.

Comment: @Vishal By adjusting `$('#table tr');` selector.

Comment: @dfsq I think you misunderstood me. I am sorry for not explaining the problem in detail. What I mean by nested tables is : When you have row and row-details like scenario. When you search for a text that is in row-details, then row details should be filtered but it should also show the parent row of row details. If its not clear then please ask. Thank you for any help.

Comment: @Vishal It's clear of course. You need to adjust $('#table tr'); selector accordingly to target nested table rows.

Comment: @dfsq sorry again. I would like to explain you that both rowdetails and its parent row are not the same `tr`. They are like this: `<tr>row</tr><tr>row-details<table>....</table></tr>`

Comment: @Vishal It doesn't matter: you need to adjust selector to target whatever tr you need, you have full control over what is searchable. I think adjacent selector is what you need.

Comment: A very helpful answer, thank you. The table I have seems to shift ever-so-slightly to the right when searching, and then moves back again as I delete text. The table has a width of 100% and the columns have a specified width, too. Any ideas what might be shifting it?

Comment: @Federer It's really difficult to say, can be anything. Try to force fixed width layout by applying `table-layout: fixed;` to table.

Comment: @dfsq thanks for the great script. I would like to insert a delete icon to text input. I can do that by changing 'type' to 'search'. Using it i can clear the input form but the rows hidden before remain hidden. I have to press enter, too. Is it possible to show the hidden rows again with out pressing enter?

Comment: how to you console log if there are no results to be able to show a no results div.

Comment: @dfsq Thank you for this, it works well! However, it won't find anything when only "i" is entered as an input using "iowa" as an example. It does work when "io" is entered. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Craig probably something with your implementation. If you could post a non-working demo, I would take a look.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks! I love the debounce functionality.

Comment: how do I include this in my html file? I tried putting it between `<script></script>` after the table code but no joy. Input and table IDs are OK, as far as I can tell, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14):

Here is the best solution for searching inside HTML table while covering ***all of the table***, (all td, tr in the table), ***pure javascript*** and as ***short*** as possible:

```
<input id='myInput' onkeyup='searchTable()' type='text'>

<table id='myTable'>
   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script>
function searchTable() {
    var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
            found = false;
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: To protect the table header row from disappearing, add id to the row like: <tr id='tableHeader'> and change the final else statement to: if (tr[i].id != 'tableHeader'){tr[i].style.display = "none";} It is not mentioned in the question but I wanted it to cover that to make it comprehensive.

Comment: Instead of comparing the id using !=, I suggest changing the final else to this:

        } else if (!tr[i].id.match('^tableHeader')) {

This allows one to have more than one table, each with their own header. More work is needed to parameterize the searchTable function by passing in the table id.

Comment: @Tarik, How to highlight matching string? like any color or bold or magnified it.

Answer (score 10):

i have an jquery plugin for this. It uses jquery-ui also. You can see an example here
http://jsfiddle.net/tugrulorhan/fd8KB/1/

```
$("#searchContainer").gridSearch({
            primaryAction: "search",
            scrollDuration: 0,
            searchBarAtBottom: false,
            customScrollHeight: -35,
            visible: {
                before: true,
                next: true,
                filter: true,
                unfilter: true
            },
            textVisible: {
                before: true,
                next: true,
                filter: true,
                unfilter: true
            },
            minCount: 2
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Pure Javascript Solution :

> Works for **ALL columns and Case Insensitive :**

```
function search_table(){
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search_field_input");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("table_id");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td") ; 
    for(j=0 ; j<td.length ; j++)
    {
      let tdata = td[j] ;
      if (tdata) {
        if (tdata.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
          break ; 
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found dfsq's answer its comments extremely useful. I made some minor modifications applicable to me (and I'm posting it here, in case it is of some use to others).

1. Using `class` as hooks, instead of table elements `tr`
2. Searching/comparing text within a child `class` while showing/hiding parent
3. Making it more efficient by storing the `$rows` text elements into an array only once (and avoiding `$rows.length` times computation)

```js
var $rows = $('.wrapper');
var rowsTextArray = [];

var i = 0;
$.each($rows, function () {
    rowsTextArray[i] = ($(this).find('.number').text() + $(this).find('.fruit').text())
        .replace(/\s+/g, '')
        .toLowerCase();
    i++;
});

$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
  $rows.show().filter(function(index) {
    return (rowsTextArray[index].indexOf(val) === -1);
  }).hide();
});
```

```css
span {
  margin-right: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="type to search" />

<div class="wrapper"><span class="number">one</span><span class="fruit">apple</span></div>
<div class="wrapper"><span class="number">two</span><span class="fruit">banana</span></div>
<div class="wrapper"><span class="number">three</span><span class="fruit">cherry</span></div>
<div class="wrapper"><span class="number">four</span><span class="fruit">date</span></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't searching for "o" even when there's o in "one, two, four"?

Comment: even "w", i guess there are many values the regex isn't searching for

Comment: That's because it was only reading the "fruit" and not the "number". I've updated it. I'd written this answer when I was very much a beginner.

Comment: LOL, everyone does something good but not that better when a beginner 

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @dfsq for the very helpful code!

I've made some adjustments and maybe some others like them too. I ensured that you can search for multiple words, without having a strict match.

Example rows:

- Apples and Pears
- Apples and Bananas
- Apples and Oranges
- ...

You could search for 'ap pe' and it would recognise the first row
You could search for 'banana apple' and it would recognise the second row

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/JeroenSormani/xhpkfwgd/1/

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase().split(' ');

  $rows.hide().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    var matchesSearch = true;
    $(val).each(function(index, value) {
      matchesSearch = (!matchesSearch) ? false : ~text.indexOf(value);
    });
    return matchesSearch;
  }).show();
});
```

Comment: Solid search -- I had to modify it slightly to prevent my Table's headers & footers from disappearing, by changing:


`var $rows = $('#WorldPlayersTable tr');`


to --


`var $rows = $('#WorldPlayersTable tbody tr');`

Answer (score 2):

you can use native javascript like this

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this will work but will remove the table headers after search no? how to make it now remove the headers ?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (and I have found faster) approach is to use `Array.from` , which allows `map`, rather than a slow for loop. Uses pure JS.

I've found this is almost instantaneous on big tables  (>1K rows). I am not sure if there is a more elegant way to save running the filter twice.

```
<input id='myInput' onkeyup='searchTable()' type='text'>

<table id='myTable'>
   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script>
function searchTable(){
    var term, table;
    // get term to search
    term = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toLowerCase();
    
    // get table rows, handle as array.
    table = Array.from(document.getElementById("myTable").rows);
    
    // filter non-matching rows; these are set to display='none'
    table.filter(function(el){return el.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) == 
    -1}).map(x=> x.style.display = "none");
    
    // filter matching rows; these are set to display =''
    table.filter(function(el){return el.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1}).map(x=> x.style.display = "");
}
</script>
```

I use a backend with templating to create the tables, if so, it's easy enough to keep your header row by adding a class to each tr:

```
<tr class="rowClass"> ... </tr>
```

and then modifying the table creation as follows to only iterate over those rows:

```
table = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("rowClass"));
```

Comment: thanks, this worked well for me! I've amended one line to only filter rows that are within the tbody element: `table = Array.from(document.getElementById("myTable").querySelectorAll("tbody tr"));`, in order to preserve the header.

Answer (score 0):

**Datatable JS plugin** is also one good alternate to accomedate search feature for html table

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// #myInput is a <input type="text"> element
$('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.search( this.value ).draw();
} );
```

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript, and new syntax:

```js
const trs = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");

document.getElementById("search").onkeyup = e => {
    for (const tr of trs)
       tr.style.display = tr.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) ? "" : "none";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can separate html and data, you can use external libraries like datatables or the one i created. https://github.com/thehitechpanky/js-bootstrap-tables

This library uses keyup function to reload tabledata and hence it appears to work like search.

```
function _addTableDataRows(paramObjectTDR) {
    let { filterNode, limitNode, bodyNode, countNode, paramObject } = paramObjectTDR;
    let { dataRows, functionArray } = paramObject;
    _clearNode(bodyNode);
    if (typeof dataRows === `string`) {
        bodyNode.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, dataRows);
    } else {
        let filterTerm;
        if (filterNode) {
            filterTerm = filterNode.value.toLowerCase();
        }
        let serialNumber = 0;
        let limitNumber = 0;
        let rowNode;
        dataRows.forEach(currentRow => {
            if (!filterNode || _filterData(filterTerm, currentRow)) {
                serialNumber++;
                if (!limitNode || limitNode.value === `all` || limitNode.value >= serialNumber) {
                    limitNumber++;
                    rowNode = _getNode(`tr`);
                    bodyNode.appendChild(rowNode);
                    _addData(rowNode, serialNumber, currentRow, `td`);
                }
            }
        });
        _clearNode(countNode);
        countNode.insertAdjacentText(`beforeend`, `Showing 1 to ${limitNumber} of ${serialNumber} entries`);
    }
    if (functionArray) {
        functionArray.forEach(currentObject => {
            let { className, eventName, functionName } = currentObject;
            _attachFunctionToClassNodes(className, eventName, functionName);
        });
    }
}
```