# HTML Table Filter with Columns

Tags: html, filter, html-table

I have set up a basic table from an example in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table) where I added column titles.

Can anyone make a suggestion how to fix the table filter so it does not hid the column titles? Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/1160/) code I have been testing.

Javascript

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

$rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
}).hide();
});
```

Example search: If you type apple in the search - it hides title 1 and title 2. However, I prefer to keep the title 1 and title 2 after the search has been entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation:  add a class into your header, and exclude that from your filter results:

http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/1161/

```html
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
    <table id="table">
         <tr class="header">
          <th>Title 1</th>
          <th>Title 2</th>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
          <td>Apple</td>
          <td>Green</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Grapes</td>
          <td>Green</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Orange</td>
          <td>Orange</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

And using [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
var $rows = $('#table tr[class!="header"]');
$('#search').keyup(function()
{
    
   var val = '^(?=.*\\b'  
                 + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') 
                 + ').*$',
                 reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
                 text;
    
   $rows.show().filter(function() 
   {
      text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
      return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
```

Comment: Howard, while your solution is going to work, there is no need to add a custom class and then negate it in the selector when you have a specific tags (thead, tbody and tfoot) in html for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the solution as well. I did not know I could add classes to tags and select them.

Answer (score 2):

Use `var $rows = $('#table tbody tr');`

Comment: The problem is about how are you filtering.. you "title" row is in fact another "standard" row in the table. The program doesn't know what is a title for you, that is why `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags exist, to tell the program what is for you the head and the body of the table.

So, you should add the `<tbody> </tbody>` tags and then use the jQuery selector as jameslafferty pointed.

Comment: The tbody tag gets inserted automagically through the mysterious intelligence of the DOM (smirk). However, @Babblo 's explanation makes why the answer works much clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This is a clear explanation and I have tested the explanation out. Also, I tested with and without <tbody> tags and they both filter as expected. Since I am still learning - I have included the tags for readability.