# Table filter not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been stuck on this for the last day and a half. I am trying get a real time filter added for my html table (which is generated off a PHP script to import a .csv file to html standard markup). I based my code off the following demo http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/2/ that I found from [How to perform a real time search and filter on a HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table) .

Now I think the issue is that the elements are not defined at time of DOM. I've tried adding the following to accommodate for this but with no luck.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {   
// My javascript  
});
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
$(document).on('pageinit')  {  
// My javascript  
});
</script>
```

and also just a plain function tag

```
<script>
$(function(){  
// My javascript  
});
</script>
```

Does anyone know how to get this js code to perform upon keystroke in my html page? (it works in the link provided above but not outside jsfiddle)

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var $rows = $('#table1 tr');
    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($('#search').val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
```

Ps. This is my first post so let me know if I did something wrong or need more explanation given. Thanks!

Comment: Does the search button exist or is that added dynamically?

Comment: I have that appearing right before the table. It looks like this    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search" style="margin-left: 20px;">

Comment: And the `var $rows = $('#table1 tr');` is inside the keyup like in the code above? Fiddle it is outside.

Comment: I've did it both ways and it wasn't making a difference.

Comment: And your table id is table1? You need to debug what is going on. console.log and debugger; is your friend.

Comment: It is table1. I looked at the debugger and it is giving me a  TypeError on this line and saying it is not a function - "$(document).ready(function() { "

Comment: Is jQuery on the page? Is it incluced before the script?

Comment: Perfect that was my issue! I'm a relative newcomer to website coding and didn't realize that jQuery needs to be loaded to the page. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're binding JS events after your DOM tree is built?

E.g. wrap your code as `ready` event listener of the document

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        //...
    }

})
```

Comment: Yes this is what I currently have. $(document).ready(function() {  
//$(function(){
 $('#search').keyup(function() {

  var $rows = $('#table1 tr');
  var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
   reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
   text;
    
  $rows.show().filter(function() {
   text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
   return !reg.test(text);
  }).hide();
 });
});