# jQuery table filter by specific columns

Tags: jquery, html, filter, html-table

I have a table of information with many names. First column is first name, second column is last name, 3rd is number. I want to show all the rows based on user input, but only want the search filter to go through specific columns with id's.

The jquery code: I have:

```
(document.ready(function()


$("#searchHere").keyup(function () {
  var $row = $("table tr");
  var $col = $("td").each().index();
  var input = this.value.toLowerCase();

  $row.show().filter(function() {
    $(this).find("td").eq(col).text().toLowerCase();
    return $(this).text(input);
  }).hide();
});
```

The HTML code

```
<input id="searchHere" placeholder="Search Me">

<table>
<tr>
  <td id='firstName'>John</td>
  <td id='lastName'>Doe</td>
  <td>One Two Three</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td id='firstName'>John</td>
  <td id='lastName'>Smith</td>
  <td>Two Three</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I've been referring to this post, but I can't figure out the last piece of the puzzle.

[How to perform a real time search and filter on a HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table)

Answer (score 0):

You could have one global search box that looks in each cell as opposed to separate inputs.

Comment: Yea, I switched to 1 search bar to look through all the TD id's.

Comment: If this has answered your question, please mark this as the solution by clicking the tick. Glad I could help :)