# Search into divs

Tags: javascript, search, indexof

I found this post [How to perform a real time search and filter on a HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table) and I would like to adapt it to search in divs.

Html :

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">  
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel 1</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel 2</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Js:

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

  $rows
    .show()
    .filter(function() {
      text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
      return !reg.test(text);
    })
    .hide();
});
```

Can someone explains how to access content into my div (and here, in "panel-heading") ?

Comment: What is the _question_?

Comment: I've just updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is invalid. `tr` element can only have `td` or `th` children. You should wrap the `tr` contents with `td` elements.

This is how my Chromium browser renders your html:

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel 1</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel 2</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Fix the markup and the JavaScript snippet will work.

Comment: I added <td> to my panels but nothing changed, i guess i don't access the "panel-heading" content right ?

Comment: Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/rh9jgwjo/ The `text` method in your code returns text content of all the `td`  children. If you just want to get the text content of the `.panel-heading` element code:   `$('.panel-heading', this).text()`

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, because there is no difference. I just wrap the `tr` contents with `td` elements.