# jQuery Real Time Search - Remove Table Header Too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am using the regular expression search code at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table), to allow real time search through a rather large table being populated server-side via php.

With a slight twist to the scenario describe in the above link, I am using table header tags to group (label) chunks of table row's together. I am preventing these table header row's from disappearing with the rest of the table row's so that when searching, the results are still nested in their group.

I would like the table header row's to disappear too, but only when there are no table row's between it and the next table header row. I'm not sure if counting row's will work, since the row's aren't gone, they're just hidden.

As an example, this is how my table is laid out:

HTML:

```
 <table>
  <tr>
     <th colspan="2">Group 1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="searchable">
    <td>Record 1</td>
    <td>Record 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="searchable">
    <th>Group 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Record 3</td>
    <td>Record 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $rows = $('tr.searchable');

    $('#search').keyup(function(e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 27) { $(this).val("") }

        var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
            reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
            text;

        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
            return !reg.test(text);
        }).hide();
    });
});
```

All help is appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my dilemma by adding another class (unique to each group/label) and within the '.keyup()' section counting the ':visible' rows of each class. Once the number of rows in each class dropped below a specified number, I used '.hide()' in an if statement to make the table headers disappear. The else side of the if statement used '.show()' to bring the table headers back if their classes count rose above the specified number.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue, it was solved by just targetting the body part for the .filter instead of the table as a whole.

```
$("#SearchPermissions").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#contentPart tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
```

Mind the $("#contentPart tr") part of the code.. this refers to the 
This way the header is excluded from the search, thus will still be displayed while filtering table data