# JavaScript HTML table search doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to run following script that I've founded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table#answer-9127872), written by [dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq) in my project.

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
```

It looks simple however I have a certain problem. It searches not in all cells in rows (looks random) and sometimes not whole words (also can't see any dependency).

For example if I have "banana" in my cell and I try to type "ban" it doesn't show anything, but when I type "ana" it shows the row.
Any idea what can go wrong?

(I cannot comment there)

[edit] I'm generating the document from php script. It may be relevant...

Comment: please write what have you tried.

Comment: I've just copied the javascript code for now on.

Comment: There is no such issue, while searching using ban or ana when there is banana in cell. See: http://jsfiddle.net/parkashkumar37/7BUmG/3761/

Comment: I know, in jsfiddle it isn't, but in my project is, and I'm trying to guess why.

Comment: And I'm using the other code. (Edited)