# PHP and HTML table search using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, search

I want to create a search box, that only displays matched entries as search phrases are typed; the same in function as described here:

[How to perform a real time search and filter on a HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table)

The difference is, the table I have is created from a PHP loop - and SQL data.  But, I am unsure how to adopt the code to work for me.

Personally, I think it could be related to the "// printing table rows" section.

Here is the code:

```js
var $search_rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $search_rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

```html
<html>

<script src="./jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="./sorttable.js"></script>
<script src="./searchbox.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<head>
<title>Tau Empire Cadre Census</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php


//// //// //// ////
// DATABASE
//// //// //// ////

//database credentials
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="tau";
$db_pwd="kuhohNg3";
$db="tau_census";
$db_table="cadres";

//make the connection
if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($db))
    die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$db_table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

//assign a variable the number of returned table fields
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);


//// //// //// ////
// HEADING
//// //// //// ////

echo "<h1>Tau Empire Cadre Census</h1>";
// Search box
echo '<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">';


//// //// //// ////
// TABLE
//// //// //// ////

//create the table, and use the JS sortable script
echo '<table id="table" class="sortable"><tr>';

// printing table headers
echo "<td class=headings>Designation</td>";
echo "<td class=headings>Location</td>";
echo "<td class=headings>Founding</td>";
echo "<td class=headings>Commanding Officer</td>";
echo "<td class=headings>Current Status</td>";
echo "<td class=headings>Current Location</td>";
echo "<td class=headings>Mission</td>";

echo "</tr>\n";

// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    // For each field print the content
    for($i=1; $i<$fields_num; $i++) {
        echo "<td>" . $row[$i] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_free_result($result);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Running this does not throw up any errors, but nor does it work either.  This requires brains greater than mine to work out, please.

Comment: What do you see in your browser console? Any error messages? What version of the jQuery library have you loaded? Is your code wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` or `$(function(){...});`?

Comment: your code here is not closing your cell properly- `</td` -> `echo "<td>$row[$i]</td";`

Comment: There are no errors in the console, nothing at all in fact.  I'm not sure how jQuery libraries work, so do not know how to find that out.  All I know is what's in the HTML; jquery-1.6.4.js.  I hadn't wrapped the code, but did try both your suggestions, neither corrected the problem; nor did either generate any errors.

Comment: Where is the `<table>` element closing tag?

Comment: so you have something like `<script src="...jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>` in your `<head>`?

Comment: @AlonEitan it was missing, have added it now.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sean No, not the min.js bit, I've only got what's on the 3rd line down in the HTML snippet.  I added "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" following another post, but that's made no difference.

Comment: @n1md4 - Looks good to me. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/v0w2xu8a/). Check your console log and if you're including the jQuery properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have this working now, thanks for all the assistance.  It was a possible combination of the following:

i) Having the following script lines inserted correctly:

```
<script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
```

ii) Wrapping the external JS in `$(function(){...});`

iii) Incorrectly constructing my table rows and data fields.

Comment: Great! And if you think we helped you here as well with the portion you posted, how about a thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you think the problem lies in the "printing table rows" section, I will point out that indeed you have formatting issues in that section, fix them like this and it might solve some of the problems:

```
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    // For each field print the content
    for($i=1; $i<$fields_num; $i++) {
        echo "<td>" . $row[$i] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: by putting the `<tr>`/`</tr>` inside the `for()` loop, they will get a row for every column, instead of a cell for every column.

Comment: right... So they'd want the tr's outside, then, edited it

Comment: That was pretty fundamental!  Thanks for the corrections.  Sadly though it is apparently not the only problem with my code, it still does not work.