# Table search with a fixed left header column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a fixed left column table and want to incorporate a search that will show the specific column not row.

So far, I've only found this which displays the row:
[How to perform a real time search and filter on a HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table/36381313#36381313?newreg=444bdad2ae4241f6a07159676ccd1f50)

But since my headers are in the column, this approach doesn't work very well.

BTW, am pretty much a javascript noob, so bear with me.. :p

Do check out my codepen which shows what I'm trying to do.
http://codepen.io/genemiester/pen/qZrpgZ

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

$rows.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !~text.indexOf(val);
}).hide();
});
```

Hope this is clear? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you could list the content in an array and search through the array. BTW, I'd like to know the function of !~ in the return statement.

Comment: Filter the source data and just rerender the table.

Comment: actually, as mentioned that i'm a js noob, the script I used is what I found for another filter function.. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Table Filter:**
Filter data as show you on in your screenshot.

Just I have changed the in JS Code **Table** to **Div** and some did some css changes. 
Once check the demo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clearsearch").click(function() {
        $("#clearsearch").fadeOut(300);
        $("#search").val("");
        $("#contentsearch div span").removeClass('success');
        $("#contentsearch div").removeClass('hide');
    });
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
        var result = $(this).val().replace(/ +?/g, "").toLowerCase();
        if (result != null && result != "") {
            $("#clearsearch").fadeIn(300);
            $("#contentsearch div").addClass('hide');
            $("#contentsearch div").find('span').each(function() {
                var tbresult = $(this).text().replace(/ +?/g, "").toLowerCase();
                if (tbresult.indexOf(result) !== -1) {
                    $(this).closest('div').removeClass('hide');
                    $(this).addClass('success');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('success');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $("#clearsearch").fadeOut(300);
            $("#contentsearch div").removeClass('hide');
            $("#contentsearch div span").removeClass('success');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.gap{ height: 10px;}
.hide{dispaly: none;}
#search{ padding-right: 15px;}
.form-group span{ position: relative; left: -24px; top: 3px; cursor: pointer; display: none;}
.form-group span:hover{ color: red;}
.success{
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
.tableheads, #contentsearch div{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
 box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(221,221,221,1);
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.tableheads span, #contentsearch div span{
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.tableheads span{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.no-border-bottom{
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
.no-border-right{
  border-right: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="clearfix gap">
    </div>
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Search :
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search">
        <span id="clearsearch" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix gap">
    </div>
    <div class="tableheads no-border-right">
      <span>Name
      </span>
      <span>State
      </span>
      <span class="no-border-bottom">Location
      </span>
    </div>
    <div id="contentsearch">
      <div class="no-border-right">
        <span>John
        </span>
        <span>Telangana
        </span>
        <span class="no-border-bottom">Hyderabad
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="no-border-right">
        <span>Nathaniel
        </span>
        <span>Andhrapradesh
        </span>
        <span class="no-border-bottom">Vijag
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="no-border-right">
        <span>Charles
        </span>
        <span>Tamilnadu
        </span>
        <span class="no-border-bottom">Chennai
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="no-border-right">
        <span>Christian
        </span>
        <span>Karnataka
        </span>
        <span class="no-border-bottom">Bangalore
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix gap">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Table - Search Demo:**
Previous demo with awesome table search option.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clearsearch").click(function() {
        $("#clearsearch").fadeOut(300);
        $("#search").val("");
        $("#tablecontent tbody tr td").removeClass('success');
        $("#tablecontent tbody tr").removeClass('hide');
    });
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
        var result = $(this).val().replace(/ +?/g, "").toLowerCase();
        if (result != null && result != "") {
            $("#clearsearch").fadeIn(300);
            $("#tablecontent tbody tr").addClass('hide');
            $("#tablecontent tbody tr").find('td').each(function() {
                var tbresult = $(this).text().replace(/ +?/g, "").toLowerCase();
                if (tbresult.indexOf(result) !== -1) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('hide');
                    $(this).addClass('success');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('success');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $("#clearsearch").fadeOut(300);
            $("#tablecontent tbody tr").removeClass('hide');
            $("#tablecontent tbody tr td").removeClass('success');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.gap{ 
    height: 10px;
}
.hide{ 
      dispaly: none;
}
#search{ 
      padding-right: 15px;
}
.form-group span{ 
      position: relative; 
      left: -24px; 
      top: 3px; 
      cursor: pointer; 
      display: none;
}
.form-group span:hover{ 
      color: red;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="clearfix gap"></div>
      <div class="form-inline">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Search :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search">
            <span id="clearsearch" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix gap"></div>
      <table id="tablecontent" class="table table-bordered">
         <thead>
            <tr class="active">
               <th>S.No.</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Country</th>
               <th>Location</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>John</td>
               <td>India</td>
               <td>Hyderabad</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>Nathaniel</td>
               <td>India</td>
               <td>Mumbai</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>Charles</td>
               <td>India</td>
               <td>Pune</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>4</td>
               <td>Christian</td>
               <td>India</td>
               <td>Secunderabad</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Eugene Goh, If you are going to use my example as reference, might as well accept it as the answer. Or is there something I did not cover?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but nope.. this isn't what I am looking for. Check out this image of what I need to achieve (based on your example) [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hffhffbmdh4npp/example.jpg?dl=0)

I actually need to search by column, not by row and to show and isolate the columns containing the keyword i'm searching for. Look at the jpeg and you'll understand. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay Thank you, @Eugene Goh, I will check it and let you know.

Comment: @Eugene Goh, I'm working on the demo, I will update you shortly. :)

Comment: hi sayed, hey this is exactly what i'm looking for, thanks heaps!!

Comment: @Eugene Goh, glad to hear that! Good luck! :), If you get solution for your query give to me up-vote to this answer please!

Comment: actually do you have your old copy for the table version? Am trying to implement this on my codepen, but it doesn't seem to work: http://codepen.io/genemiester/pen/qZrpgZ

Comment: Okay @Eugene Goh, I will check it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i hope this is what you were aiming for

```js
var $rows = $('table tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  var regular_expression = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(val));

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !text.match(regular_expression);
  }).hide();
});

function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search">

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>google</td>
      <td>Bing</td>
      <td>Search Engine</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Opera</td>
      <td>Chrome</td>
      <td>FireFox</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but nope.. not what I'm looking for.. your search is still isolating the row and not the column which is what I need. I want to be able to see the whole column.. not the row as my headers are in the left most fixed column.. if the search only shows a row, the user will only see data for that one header. i want the user to be able to see the whole column so that they can see the rest of the column data for that entity.