# how to search multiple columns in a table using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a searchbox as below:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="myInput"/>
```

and I have a table with id="show_member" with different columns.
I have written a code as below and I would like to search all columns whenever I type something in the searchbox(the input above)
What is the problem with the code and how can I fix it?
Not only doesn't it show the related columns but also it doesn't get removed when I delete all the letters in the search box.

```
    function myFunction(){
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
//alert(input.value);
var iv = input.value;
var rows = $('table tr').hide().filter(":contains(".'iv'.")").show();
}
```

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: There are several examples out there for this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table
And even a simple library if you're so inclined: http://listjs.com/

Comment: you are making `iv` as string instead of a variable reference. Just remove the single quotes around it.

Comment: `":contains(".'iv'.")")` this is php.

Comment: whenever I search, the <th> i mean the head part of my table is deleted.
What should I do to disable it from deleting?

Comment: You can ignore the first row `'tr:not(:first)'`

Comment: I wrote this but it didn't work:
$('table tr:not(:first)').hide().filter(":contains("+iv+")").show();
any other ways?

Comment: I found the answer somewhere else
thanks Satpal for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `+` for [string operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators)(concatenation) in JavaScript

```
$('table tr').hide().filter(":contains(" + iv +")").show();
```

instead of

```
$('table tr').hide().filter(":contains(".'iv'.")").show()
```