# Cannot change HTML content dynamically using JavaScript input search?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used a search box to search contact details of persons. There are 4 contacts initially:

1)`"Jonathan Buell",5804337551,"family"`

2)`"Patrick Daniel",8186934432,"work"`

3) `"Lorraine Winter",3138211928,"work"`

4) `"Constance Reed",3138211928,"family"`

Lets say now if I type `j` in input box it should show only `Jonathan Buell` if I type `Lorr` in input then it should display `Lorraine Winter` contact details. If the string does not match if user types `xyz` then it should not display any contact.

I tried to implement above search feature but it does not change the content dynamically no change is observed.

Index.html:

```js
var array = [];

function Person(fullName, number, group) {
  this.fullName = fullName;
  this.number = number;
  this.group = group;
  array.push(this);
}

var p1 = new Person("Jonathan Buell", 5804337551, "family");
var p2 = new Person("Patrick Daniel", 8186934432, "work");
var p3 = new Person("Lorraine Winter", 3138211928, "work");
var p4 = new Person("Constance Reed", 3138211928, "family");

console.log(array);

function showContacts() {
  for (var i in array) {
    var id = i;
    contactlist.innerHTML +=
      `
             <ul>
             <div>
             <p>Name: ` + array[i].fullName + `</p>
             <p>Number: ` + array[i].number + `</p>
             <p>Group: ` + array[i].group + `</p>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="editContact(` + id + `)">Edit</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
             </div>
             `
  }
}

showContacts();

function search() {
  var search = document.getElementById("search").value;

  contactlist.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i in array) {
    if (array[i].fullName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
      var id = i;
      contactlist.innerHTML =
        `
               <ul>
               <div>
               <p>Name: ` + array[i].fullName + `</p>
               <p>Number: ` + array[i].number + `</p>
               <p>Group: ` + array[i].group + `</p>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="editContact(` + id + `)">Edit</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
               </div>
               </ul>
               `;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>

  <div id="contactlist">

  </div>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Screenshot of my app :

[image]

Comment: You really shouldn't tether a class constructor to push to an external array, but rather push `new Person(...)` into the array.

Comment: You use in your javascript code the `´ to wrap html code. Maybe this is one reason for you problem.

Comment: I do not see any event attached to your search input change calling `search()`

Comment: Side-note, don't do this: `<p>Name: \`+ array[i].fullName + \`</p>`, the whole advantage of [template strings is interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Instead, do `<p>Name: ${array[i].fullName}</p>`

Comment: @Striped Why to call `search()` lets say if I type `j` then it should dynamically change contact list and show `Jonathan Buell` as `j` matches to `J` of `Jonathan Buell`

Comment: @SterlingArcher lets say if I type j then it should dynamically change contact list and show Jonathan Buell as j matches to J of Jonathan Buell.

Comment: this appears to be pretty much the [exact same question you asked one hour before this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48664728/how-to-implement-search-feature-using-vanilla-javascript). Please don't ask the same question multiple times, edit the original if you need to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement search feature using vanilla javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48664728/how-to-implement-search-feature-using-vanilla-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this one, it works perfect with jquery

```
$(".search").on("input",function(){

        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

        // Loop through the comment list
        $("#contactlist .main_div").each(function(){

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();

                // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });
    });
```

and when you add divs, give a class to the parent div like this

```
for (var i in array) {
    if (array[i].fullName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
      var id = i;
      contactlist.innerHTML =
        `
                        <ul>
                        <div class="main_div">
                        <p>Name: ` + array[i].fullName + `</p>
                        <p>Number: ` + array[i].number + `</p>
                        <p>Group: ` + array[i].group + `</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="editContact(` + id + `)">Edit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                        </ul>
                        `;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: with the class that you add you can loop through each user, just try it and let me know

Comment: I am trying to replicate the feature from this project -> https://github.com/snwolak/contact-list-app/blob/4c525e35146afd987c6e6f4edda0bf0fb44af333/src/app.js#L181  Check the live demo  -> https://snwolak.github.io/contact-list-app/

Comment: did you saw the demo and the code for `search()` it is not called explicitly but it still works in demo why so ?

Comment: this is the same, just try it

Comment: see fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/tj0gcnf4/10/) I made with your example , it works perfect

Comment: I want to implement it in vanill JS and not using jquery can you please tell me how to do it using vanilla JS your jquery code works like a charm that's what I am trying to implement but using vanilla JS. Why is my ocde not working as I am doing same thing mentioned here -> https://github.com/snwolak/contact-list-app/blob/4c525e35146afd987c6e6f4edda0bf0fb44af333/src/app.js#L181

Comment: My solution is to implement Jquery into your project and you will have no prob, I am not familiar with that example that you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

On its own, your search input knows nothing of your JavaScript array or its contents. And your `search()` function is never called; placing an id of search on your input doesn't associate that input with the function.

What you *can* do is add an event listener to your search input which listens for the `enter` keypress, after which point your array of people can be filtered.

Something like this:

```
// You imported jQuery, so you may as well use $("#search") instead of document.getElementById("search")
var search_input = $('#search')

search_input.keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        // If the enter key was pressed
        search()
    }
})

function search(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var search_val = search_input.val();

    contactlist.innerHTML = '';

    for(var i in array) {
        if (array[i].fullName.toLowerCase().includes(search_val.toLowerCase())) {
            var id = i;
            contactlist.innerHTML = `
                <ul>
                    <div>
                        <p>Name: `+ array[i].fullName +`</p>
                        <p>Number: `+ array[i].number +`</p>
                        <p>Group: `+ array[i].group +`</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="editContact(`+ id +`)">Edit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            `;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to replicate the feature from this project -> https://github.com/snwolak/contact-list-app/blob/4c525e35146afd987c6e6f4edda0bf0fb44af333/src/app.js#L181    Live demo of the project can be seen here -> https://snwolak.github.io/contact-list-app/

Comment: did you saw the demo and the code for search() it is not called explicitly but it still works in demo why so ?

Comment: The reason why that works in the demo is because in `index.html` their input has an attribtue of `onkeyup="search()"`

Comment: So should I call `search()` in my input then will it work ?

Comment: Yes, but you won't get suggestions without additional code

Comment: with `onkey="search()"` it works like a charm now :) thanks

Comment: I'm glad to hear it!