# javascript search has no effect

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to get a searchable html table.

Based on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table) and the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/2/) I thought including the search script with `<script></script>` should work:

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id="table">
   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script>
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
</script>
```

The above snippet *does* work when I try it on jsfiddle. But if I write this to an html locally and open it in a browser it has no effect.

What am I missing?

Comment: You get no errors in the console at all?

Comment: it's actually working fine locally for me, can you please be specific about what error you are getting?

Comment: hey @TBA the edit you suggested (including `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`) actually fixed it for me. So it seems the script needs jquery

Comment: Happy to help ^_^ and always remember to first check your console for this kind of problem or you can say any JS problem. :p

Comment: @TBA how do I check my console?

Comment: @TBA never mind, figured it out, many thanks

Comment: @the.real.gruycho hey sorry, I was actually in Dreamland  console is used for debugging purpose, you can show output in the browsers by just typing console.log(). [Check here more details](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/console).

Comment: Open the developer tool in chrome by pressing either f12 or Ctrl+shift+I. You will find many tabs there with console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need `jquery`. Adding this will fix it:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Inspecting the console log can sometimes provide information about errors.

E.g. Chromium you can view it with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I` and with your original snippet you will see:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at test.html:18
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your javascript code after page loaded by wrapping like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
   // your js code here
})
```